# Nitty gritty in Euclid's GCD Algorithm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For a division expression where $a$ and $b$ are two positive integers such that $a>b$ we can write it as :

$a = bq + r$   ($q$ is quotient and $r$ is remainder from division)

While finding GCD of $a$ and $b$, I come to an intuitive conclusion that the common factor $k$ of $a$ and $b$ should satisfy : 
$\frac{1}{2}b> k$ and $\frac{1}{2}r>$ $k$ if $r$ is a positive non-zero integer.

I want to prove to myself that $k$ must be smaller than $r$ and that there exists no common factor if $r$ is non-zero positive integer such that $k > r$.

To do so, I used the basic principle :

$$\text{gcd}(a,b) = \text{gcd}(b,r)$$

Therefore, the common factor of a and b must be smaller than or equal to $r$ because you cannot have a factor greater than number itself.

I want to know if there is any other possibility of arriving at a contradiction if we start with a premise that $k > r$ when $r>0$ .

Comment: You wrote $\frac{1}{2} r>$ without a right hand side.

Comment: it is possible that $\gcd(a,b) = b.$

Comment: @DougM - In that case the remainder would be a non-zero positive integer but otherwise the condition has to be true. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Ian : Thank you for alert. +1.

Comment: @ultimate cause You need more conditions still, say $a=2$ and $b=4,$ then $\text{gcd}(a,b)=r=2=(1/2)b.$

Comment: @Melody I mentioned the precondition : a > b

Comment: Let $a=8$ and $b=6.$ Then $q=1$ and $r=2=\gcd (8,6).$ But $(r=2\land r/2>k)\implies 1>k.$